# Prev and next button for an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please go to this codepen https://codepen.io/CodingGilbert/pen/xJGvQB?editors=1010

In the main section where all items are, everything works perfect. However, if you go to “dresses” and you click the “quickview” button of any object except the first one and click next, it will skip one item of the array. I mean the prev and next button functionality is not working as in the main section, even when I'm changing the parameter of the swapPopup for a new filtered array `filteredData`

This is hard to explain for me, but if you visit the codepen, go to dresses or tops section, click the quickview button of any item except the first one and open the console, you will see the situation that I am trying to explain. This behavior is happening in all of the sections from the navigation btw. But everything works perfectly in the main section where all items are located and that's the weird part of this.

The following code it's all the code related to this functionality. `data` is the array containing all my 38 objects. Any help is much appreciated.

```js
const data = [
  {
    product: "Haori Jacket",
    url: "haorijacket.html",
    image: "img/haori-jacket.jpg",
    altDesc: "Jacket",
    price: "$210.00",
    category: "outwear"
  },
  {
    product: "Swing Dress",
    url: "swingdress.html",
    image: "img/swing-dress.jpg",
    altDesc: "Dress",
    price: "$218.00",
    category: "dresses"
  },
  {
    product: "Dusty Jumpsuit",
    url: "",
    image: "img/dusty-jumpsuit.jpg",
    altDesc: "Jumpsuit",
    price: "$299.00",
    sale: "$399.00",
    category: "dresses"
  },
  ...
 ];

// Generate template literal
const clothingView = (item, index) =>
    `<a href="${item.url}" class="shop-item">
    ${item.sale ? `<span class="shop-item__sale">Sale</span>`: ''}
      <img data-src=${item.image} alt="${item.altDesc}" class="shop-item__img">
      <div class="quickview">
        <span class="quickview__icon">Quick View</span>
        <span class="quickview__info">${item.product}
          <br>
          <span class="quickview__price">${item.price}
            ${item.sale ? `<span class="quickview__price--sale">${item.sale}</span>`: ''}
          </span>
        </span>
        <span class="shop-item__index">${index}</span>
      </div>
    </a>`;

// Append template literal to html structure based on category
data.map((item, index) => {
  const showItems = clothingView(item, index);

  $('.all-items').append(showItems);
  $('.' + item.category).append(showItems);
  item.sale ? $('.sale').append(showItems) : null
});

// Filtering data from array based on category
let navCategoryClicked;
let filteredData = [];
$('.categories__link').click(function() {
  navCategoryClicked = true;
  const category = this.id;
  let filteringData;

  if (category === 'bottoms') {
    filteringData = data.filter(el => el.category === 'bottoms');
  } else if (category === 'tops') {
    filteringData = data.filter(el => el.category === 'tops');
  } else if (category === 'outwear') {
    filteringData = data.filter(el => el.category === 'outwear');
  } else if (category === 'accessories') {
    filteringData = data.filter(el => el.category === 'accessories');
  } else if (category === 'dresses') {
    filteringData = data.filter(el => el.category === 'dresses');
  } else {
    filteringData = data.filter(el => el.sale);
  }

  filteredData = filteringData;
  console.log(filteredData);
});

// Change clothing-item popup window img and info
const swapPopup = clothing => {
  $('#clothingLink').prop('href', clothing.url)
  $('#clothingImg').prop('src', clothing.image)
  $('#clothingName').text(clothing.product)
  $('#clothingPrice').text(clothing.price)
  clothing.sale ? $('#clothingSale').text(clothing.sale) : $('#clothingSale').text(null)
};

// Change cloting-item img and info
let currentPopup;
$('.quickview__icon').click(function(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.overlay').css({'opacity': '1', 'visibility': 'visible'});

  currentPopup = $(e.target).parent().children('.shop-item__index').text();
  swapPopup(data[currentPopup]);
});

let dataArr;
$('#popupPrev').click(function() {
  navCategoryClicked != true ? dataArr = data : dataArr = filteredData;
  currentPopup > 0 ? --currentPopup : currentPopup = dataArr.length - 1;
  swapPopup(dataArr[currentPopup]);
  console.log(currentPopup);
});

$('#popupNext').click(function() {
  navCategoryClicked != true ? dataArr = data : dataArr = filteredData;
  currentPopup < dataArr.length -1 ? ++currentPopup : currentPopup = 0;
  swapPopup(dataArr[currentPopup]);
  console.log(currentPopup);
});
```

Comment: It's because you're not determining the item's new index after filtering the results. E.g. "Sonia dress" is at index 4 on the homepage. So when you go to dresses and open it, then hit next, it goes to index 5 (even though on the dress page it's only at index 2)

Comment: Yes that was my first thought, that's why I tried this but it didn't work `// Change cloting-item img and info
let currentPopup;
$('.quickview__icon').click(function(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.overlay').css({'opacity': '1', 'visibility': 'visible'});

  navCategoryClicked != true ? dataArr = data : dataArr = filteredData;
  currentPopup = $(e.target).parent().children('.shop-item__index').text();
  swapPopup(dataArr[currentPopup]);
});` I have to try another approach, any ideas?